# Prove that the twisted Convolution of $f$ and $g$ lies in $L^2(C^n)$?

Tags: convolution

Edit,this is the **exact phrasing** of my question

> Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R^n}$.Prove that
>
> $f\star_{\lambda}g\in L^2(\mathbb{C^n})$ for all functions $f$ and $g$
> in $L^2(\mathbb{C^n})$.What Happens when $\lambda=0?$

I been reading the book Harmonic Analysis on the Heisenberg Group
By Sundaram Thangavelu and on Page 16,it explains that the twisted convolution turns $L^1(C^n)$ into a non-communicative Banach algebra
[image]

**I define a twisted convolution as follows,*The definition of a twisted convolution follows
[image: Definition of Twisted Convolution]
Where $[z,w]$ is the Symplectic form given by
[image: Definition of the Symplectic form of [z,w]]

I want to prove that the twisted convolution for $f$ and $g$ lies in $L^2(C^n)$**How to you prove this fact?**
I note that when $\lambda=0$,they do not lie in $L^2(C^n)$.
Here is my attempt at the question when $\lambda=0$  does not lie in $L^2(C^n)$.
My Attempt when $\lambda=0$,I want to note that $f$ and $g$ are Swartz functions
[image: My attempt]
[[image: My attempt at proving that the normal convolution(when <span class=]$\lambda=0$) of $f$ and $g$ does not lie in $L^2(C^n)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJX20.jpg)

How do I approach this more general case?
I been reading numerous references to help me solve this problem such as

1. Pseudo-Differential Operators, Generalized Functions and Asymptotics
2. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/07/26/twisted-convolution-and-the-sensitivity-conjecture/
   and numerous other sources and still could not figure it out

What specific function would you use to prove this fact? I need some assistance here,and what specific function can you use to prove this fact?

Or could you reference me to another book that has a chapter about the identities and full proofs related to twisted convolutions

I been stuck on this problem for 2 days and need help.

Comment: This would fit much better over at math.stackexchange.

Comment: @MattL. I solved it